# Have a dict in double quoted string trying to convert it into normal dict using json.loads but getting json decode error

Tags: python, json

Trying to get the dictionary from string using json.loads but getting Exception `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`.

Below is the exact string value in `contract_details` for anyone to try:

```
contract_details = "{'instrumentToken': 17098, 'instrumentName': 'BANKNIFTY', 'name': nan, 'lastPrice': 333.05, 'expiry': '07OCT21', 'strike': 37800.0, 'tickSize': 0.05, 'lotSize': 25, 'instrumentType': 'OI', 'segment': 'FO', 'exchange': 'NSE', 'isin': nan, 'multiplier': 1, 'exchangeToken': 40728, 'optionType': 'PE'}"

contract_details = current_order["contract_details"]
contract_details = json.loads(contract_details)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear, try to modify it: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to clear your question, ebsides it's look like 'contract_details' got str and not dict

Comment: The json module is for loading JSON. A dict in quotes is not JSON. Either your input *should be* JSON, then its source must be fixed, or it *should not* be JSON, then you should not treat it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` suggests  , `json` expects strings to have double quotes around the values inside the string. You can change the source if possible or replace the single quotes with double quotes using `replace("'", '"')` on `contract_details`, you also need to replace `'nan'` with `'NaN'`

```
json.loads(contract_details.replace("'", '"').replace('nan', 'NaN'))
```

Comment: getting JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 67 (char 66)

Comment: @sahil see updated answer.